# How can I split .ape files?

Tags: audio, music

When I try to use Medieval Cue Splitter for an `.ape` file I get this:

```
Could not find MACDII.dll (version 4.0 or better) on your system. APE file engine was disabled.
```

Is there a way to do this in Cue Splitter? Or is there some other software that can split `.ape` files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

download and install the latest version of **[Monkey's Audio](http://monkeysaudio.com/download.html)**

Comment: Oooh...Monkey's Audio creates .APE files - I get it!

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest [CUETools](http://www.cuetools.net/wiki/Main_Page) when the `*.cue` file is available. It splits the file when *Mode > **Tracks*** is selected.

[image: CUETools, Encode, Tracks]

It also connects to an [online ripping accuracy database](http://wiki.hydrogenaudio.org/index.php?title=AccurateRip) to query data:

[image: CUETools -- AccurateRip]